# What is the MSTest Attribute for including a test resource?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I want to have a test resource that is available during my test and I know there is an attribute that deploys the item.

What is the attribute?

Comment: I believe it depends on the unit testing framework you're using, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes it does depend on unit testing framework.  I put MSTest in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[DeploymentItem("myFile1.txt")]`
[MSDN Doc on DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx)

This is really useful if you are testing against a file or using the file as input to your test.

Comment: Here's a good website on this attribute:
http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2007/10/gotchas-mstests-deploymentitem-attribute/

Answer (score 3):

That really depends. Personally I **hate** the way that MSTest does this - either with the attribute *or* the separate "testrunconfig" file (add items in the "Deployment" section). I prefer the NUnit way (I use it with TestDriven.NET) - then if you want it to include a file in the output you do exactly what you would in regular VS projects; you toggle the "Copy to Output Directory" property.